# Creating new Asynctask to call a method again

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm trying to call startRunning() method, which works the first time i click the button and it executes, but if i try to do it again, it simply does nothing. It only logs the "connectToPc, connect. It doesn't actually call the startRunning method..
What do i have to change to make it work? I thought just creating a new instance of the asynctask would make it work, but for some reason it doesnt?
I tried searching some other posts about it, but with no luck - anyone who has a solution? :)

The method startRunning() tries to establish a socket connection to a server waiting to be connected.

Thanks in advance

```
public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private MainActivityFragment activity;

    public myAsyncTask(MainActivityFragment activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        activity.startRunning();
        return null;
    }
}
```

In a different class:

```
public void connectOnClick(){

        //TODO: trying to connecting and failing multiple times doesn't work properly. Fix This.
        try {
           new myAsyncTask(this).execute("");

            Log.w("connectToPC","Connect");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what does `startRunning();` do? Why do you need to reference a method from your `Activity` in a background thread? Post method code.  BTW passing your `Activity` reference into an AsyncTask is asking for memory leaks.

Comment: @MarkKeen the problem is not so much what the startRunning does. Since it never really calls that method the second time i try and run the new myAsyncTask()

Comment: Well my guess is that `startRunning();` does not complete the first time, so calling a new `AsyncTask();` means it gets queued waiting for the First to return to `onPostExecute();`.  Your log statement `Log.w("connectToPC","Connect");` is shown each time as `new myAsyncTask(this).execute("");` returns immediately and is non blocking (the purpose of an `AsyncTask`). You could use an Executor for multiple background threads, however if the first is not completing there is a bigger issue

Comment: @MarkKeen well, the first one doesn't "complete", unless you break the connection. I'd like it to complete the asyncTask if the connection is lost. Is there a method for asynctask that lets you stop the current execution?

Comment: from the Android Developers page : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html  I could explain, but they do a thorough job - look for "Cancelling a task" section

Comment: @MarkKeen just a finishing question. If i would use Thread t = new Thread(){ 

public void run(){
startRunning();
}};
t.start();

If i executed this several times, would there be a lot of old threads left in the background?

Comment: You can use a `Thread` and create your own logic, however AsyncTask obviously uses a `Thread` along with `Handlers`, `Messages` & `Runnables` and has convenient callbacks. One thing to note, Activities get destroyed and recreated, so if you start an AsyncTask from an Activity and a configuration change occurs then the reference it calls back to will be null, Also in your case you are holding a reference to your Activity in your AsyncTask, so if the Activity is destroyed an d recreated the old Activity can't be Garbage Collected.  If you have a long running task then consider using a `Service`